# My ArrayList is not returning the correct output (must write file directory to csv file)

Tags: java, arraylist, directory

I'm doing a java program that prints a file directory on my computer. I  have 3 classes, the `MyFile` class (to write to the file), the `ListFiles` class (to retrieve the files and attributes of the directory), and the `Folder` class (to create a folder object of the specific directory address). My output produces everything correctly, except for the fact that it does not write to my csv file and my minimum and maximum are either the same or the minimum is 0. I have only been programming java for 8 months, so i'm sure it's an easy solution to most people, but for me I'm not sure where to even start with my logic error. I appreciate all input and thank you! Here's my code.

I have created three arraylists to retrieve the contents of my directory and essentially write it to the csv file, I have also attempted initializing my minimum and maximum variables to different values in order to get the correct size.

```
public class ListFiles {
    ArrayList<Folder> theFolder = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ///call ListFiles
        new ListFiles();


    }

    ////ListFiles method to print whether it exists 
    public ListFiles() {

        String dname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a path for folder: ");
        File f = new File(dname);
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Exists");
            showFiles(dname, " ");

       ArrayList<String> callShowFiles = showFiles(dname, " ");
       ArrayList<Folder> callGetDirectoryInfo = getDirectoryInfo(callShowFiles);
       ArrayList<String> callGetFolderInfo = getFolderInfo(callGetDirectoryInfo); 
       MyFile.myFileWriter(callGetFolderInfo, "FileDirectory.csv");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Does not exist");

        }
    }

    ///show files (find child file name, parent file name, extensions, subfolder count, min, max, and avg of files
    public ArrayList<String> showFiles(String dirName, String idn) {

        System.out.println("START ------------------------");

        //create indent
        String indent = idn;
        ///create new file for direcctory name
        File file = new File(dirName);
        ///create index for dirName (lastIndexOf) to print out the last thing 

        int index = dirName.lastIndexOf('\\');

        ///get and print name of parent file
        File fileParent = file.getParentFile();
        Folder folder = new Folder(dirName.substring(index + 1));
        folder.setParent(fileParent.getPath());
        int indexForParent = folder.getParent().lastIndexOf("\\");
        folder.parent = folder.getParent().substring(indexForParent);

        ///find amount of subfolders
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            folder.folderCount = file.list().length;
            System.out.println("Subfolder Count:" + folder.folderCount);
            ///folder.name = name
            folder.name = name;
            String[] files = file.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                File childFile = new File(dirName + "\\" + files[i]);
                //int folderCount, int max, int avg, int min, String parent, String name, int totalSize, int fileCount, int xl, int ppt, int doc

                if (childFile.isDirectory()) {
                    showFiles(dirName + "\\" + files[i], indent + " ");

                } else {

                    ///if the file count is 0, it is a file
                }
                if (folder.fileCount == 0) {
                    folder.fileCount++;
                    ///set size to length of childfile
                    int size = (int) childFile.length();

                    ///set min, max, and totalsize to size
                    folder.min = size;
                    folder.max = size;
                    folder.totalSize = size;

                    ///if max is less than current size, max = size
                    if (folder.getMax() < size) {
                        folder.setMax(size);
                        // folder.fileCount++;

                        ///if min is greater than current size, min == size
                    } else if (folder.getMin() > size) {
                        folder.setMin(size);
                        //folder.fileCount++;
                    } else {
                        ////else fileCount increases and totalSIze increases
                        folder.fileCount++;
                        //folder.totalSize += size;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


String folders =("Name: "+folder.name+"\nParent: "+ folder.parent+"\nFolder Count: "+ folder.folderCount+"\nFile Count: "+ folder.fileCount
       +"\nTotal Size: "+folder.totalSize+"\nMin: "+ folder.min+"\nMax: "+folder.max+"\nAvg: "+ folder.avg
      +"\nDocs: "+folder.doc+"\nXl: "+ folder.xl+"\nPpt: "+ folder.ppt);
                      ArrayList <String> print = new ArrayList();
                       print.add(folders);

        System.out.println("END ------------------------\n");
        return print;


    }
     public ArrayList<Folder> getDirectoryInfo(ArrayList<String> list){
        ArrayList<Folder> emp = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 1; i< list.size(); i++){
            String str = list.get(i);
            String fields[] = str.split(",");

            Folder e =new Folder(fields[0].trim(),
                        fields[1].trim(),
                        Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[3].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[4].trim()),
                        Integer.parseInt(fields[5].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[6].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[7].trim()),
                        Integer.parseInt(fields[8].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[9].trim()),Integer.parseInt(fields[10].trim()));


            emp.add(e);
     }
        ///takes a string arraylist and returns folder list of fields to be wrote to csv file
        return emp;
    }


      public ArrayList<String> getFolderInfo(ArrayList<Folder> emp){
        ArrayList<String> stringFiles = new ArrayList();
        stringFiles.add("Testing");
        for(int i = 0; i < emp.size(); i++){
            String str = emp.get(i).getName() + " , " +emp.get(i).getParent() + " , " + emp.get(i).getFolderCount() + " , "+emp.get(i).getFileCount()
                    + " , " + emp.get(i).getTotalSize()+" , "+emp.get(i).getMin()+" , "+emp.get(i).getMax()
                    +" , "+emp.get(i).getAvg() + " , "+emp.get(i).getDoc() + " , "+emp.get(i).getXl()+" , "+emp.get(i).getPpt();
            stringFiles.add(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        return stringFiles;
    }

}
```

Here is my folder class

```
public class Folder {

    String name;
    String parent;
    int folderCount;
    int fileCount;
    int totalSize;
    int min, max, avg;
    int doc, xl, ppt;

    public Folder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Folder(String name, String parent, int folderCount, int fileCount, int totalSize, int min, int max, int avg, int doc, int xl, int ppt) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.folderCount = folderCount;
        this.fileCount = fileCount;
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
        this.doc = doc;
        this.xl = xl;
        this.ppt = ppt;
    }

    public int getFileCount() {
        return fileCount;
    }

    public void setFileCount(int fileCount) {
        this.fileCount = fileCount;
    }

    public int getTotalSize() {
        return totalSize;
    }

    public void setTotalSize(int totalSize) {
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
    }

    public int getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(int doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public int getXl() {
        return xl;
    }

    public void setXl(int xl) {
        this.xl = xl;
    }

    public int getPpt() {
        return ppt;
    }

    public void setPpt(int ppt) {
        this.ppt = ppt;
    }

    public int getFolderCount() {
        return folderCount;
    }

    public void setFolderCount(int folderCount) {
        this.folderCount = folderCount;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getAvg() {
        return avg;
    }

    public void setAvg(int avg) {
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

And here is my MyFile Class (I'm 100% sure the code for this is correct though, it
 should be an error in ListFiles)

```
public class MyFile {

    public static ArrayList myFileReader(String fname) {

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            File file = new File(fname);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myList.add(st);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myList;
    }

    public static void myFileWriter(ArrayList<String> list, String fname){
        try {
            File file = new File(fname);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fname);
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                pw.println(list.get(i));
            }
            pw.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

I expect it to print all of the fields/output of my file directory (parent, name, total size, folder count, min/max, etc.) to the .csv file and for the minimum size to be smaller than the maximum size. The only thing wrote to my.csv file is 'Testing' and my minimum size is the same as my maximum size or 0, even with multiple files in the directory.

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at, which is probably why no one has figured this out for you. I would add debug statements and output to the screen the info you're collecting to see if you're really collecting what you think you're collecting, and if you're really calling the code you think you're calling.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll try that, because it's writing my statement to the file, but not my arraylist, which is really weird.

Comment: Just wanted to add an update, after some painstakingly repetitive work, I have managed to debug my program. The only thing wrong with it now is that it won't return the correct minimum and maximum size :)

Comment: A common cause of bad min/max management is how you initialize the original values and how you compare. Min is more likely mishandled than max as people tend to initialize default values of 0 and then do if newsize < minsize -- which is rarely the case, as minsize is probably 0. You can initialize to -1 and then if minsize == -1 || newsize < minsize, or something along those lines.